# How to access to the {window, location} in the gatsby-theme-material-ui-top-layout

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

How can I access to the {window, location} in the gatsby-theme-material-ui-top-layout/components/top-layout

Do I have to use gatsby-plugin-layout?

Can I use both instead gatsby-plugin-layout and gatsby-theme-material-ui?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need extra plugins to do that. You have a bunch of options to achieve this, but without any code provided it's difficult to guess which one fits your requirements or specifications. You can access the `window` object at any time, keeping in mind that your code may throw an error on `build` command, so:

- Place your code inside a `componentDidMount` lifecycle or a `useEffect` hook which ensures the code doesn’t run unless it’s in the browser, where the `window` will be defined.
- Use a condition before you execute your statement:

  `if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        //your code here
      }`
- Another option is that your code uses a third-party module/library that needs the `window` to be defined before, so, when Gatsby builds (compiles and bundles) all your assets, your code may throw an error due to the needs of the library and the undefinition of the `window` object at that moment, in that case, you need to change your webpack loader to `null`. In your `gatsby-node.js`:

  `exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
    if (stage === "build-html") {
      actions.setWebpackConfig({
        module: {
          rules: [
            {
              test: /bad-module/,
              use: loaders.null(),
            },
          ],
        },
      })
    }
  }`